# Why does PHP install so many version folders?

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian, xdebug

new to linux, I installed php on debian9 with the following commands...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ca-certificates apt-transport-https
apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-opcache php7.2-curl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-zip php7.2-xml
```

Later I needed XDebug I installed via the following

```
sudo apt install php-xdebug
```

phpinfo was displaying xdebug present

[image]

and I went configuring **/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini** with

[image]

I never got remote debugging to work neither from vscode or phpstorm.  However, on Windows7 I managed to have more success and fixed my php deprecated code from 5.x to 7.x

Now I needed on curl and mbstring extensions on the linux side.

I enabled those extensions in **/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini**

```
extension_dir = "./"
extension=curl
extension=mbstring
```

and I ALSO run the the following according to a post.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring  # Debian, Ubuntu
```

I think that's when XDebug disappeared from phpinfo

[image]
[image]

After a couple of sudo update/upgrade

```
[![enter image description here][5]][5]
```

now php -i | grep "php.ini" shows php switched from 7.2 to 7.4 ???

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

yet the 1st line of phpinfo still says 7.0

```
PHP Version 7.0.33-25+0~20200225.32+debian9~1.gbpa11893
```

, I am totally confused.  php -m lists curl, mbstring, and xdebug.

FileZilla shows me all these folders under php and I have, like 10, php.ini both under **cli/** and **apache2/**  a real frustration as to what to edit???

[image]

Summary: simple php runs (eg. echo, phpinfo(), ... ), but my script calls curl and mb_convert_encoding() which I think must be failing.

Comment: `update-alternatives --query php` to bring some order, or remove stray versions via aptitude/synaptic. Cli and apche will always have separate configs.

Comment: @mario thanks, is that one command?  `sudo update-alternatives --query php`   then you mention remove stray versions, what command? thank you.

Comment: @mario I really need only one version like latest 7.4, can I delete all of /etc/php folder and start over? I am sure there must a command for that in linux (ie. de-install all of php) I will follow your recommendations. Thanks

Comment: @mario I found purge should I issue a series of `sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.1 php7.2 php7.3`  and thus leaving only php7.4  (just a wild guess)

Comment: `apt-cache search php` will list available packages from all mashed up repos, if you still insist on tedious manual management, `dpkg --purge` to get rid of individual config dirs.

Comment: @mario, I remove/purge all php, then apt-get install php7.4 then install php-xdebug, between just those 2 commands they re-instated all folders 5.6, 7.0...7.4 yuck! XDebug showed up in phpinfo, however the moment I uncomment `extension_dir = "./"` in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` it disappears, is that normal?